# Excel formula index match with criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have database with two columns, Helper with reference numbers and SPH code. This data has multiple values. Thus, for one reference we have multiple SPH codes (SPH code options VEH, ENG, HEL or Other).

[image]

I have created a second sheet with the Helper unique values, and I want to do a formula that searches for the SPH code and since there is multiple options, does the search based on certain conditions.

VEH, ENG, HEL are never together under the same reference, if there is VEH, ENG or HEL give those, if none of those write other.

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: *if there is VEH, ENG or HEL give those, if none of those write other.* Do you mean to check if for a specific helper reference number it's associated to  VEH, ENG **and** HEL at the same time?

Comment: No, the three codes are never going to be together you have for example VEH and Other in that case the outcome is VEH, if it is Other and ENG then ENG, if it is Other and Other then Other

Comment: In the above example, I see two "helper" numbers associated with 5 text tags total, 2 of them are from your target group. What exactly do you want your formula to return in this example? Just one of these tags in a cell? A range of all target tags? Or something else?

Also, is it possible that the same number will be associated with 2 or more of target tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[image]

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$15;D3;$B$2:$B$15;"ENG")>0;"ENG";IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$15;D3;$B$2:$B$15;"VEH")>0;"VEH";IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$15;D3;$B$2:$B$15;"HEL")>0;"HEL";"Other")))
```

It's just to combine COUNTIFS with IF and check which condition is met